# Excel VBA export selected sheets to PDF in a selected number of copies

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

The Workbook consists of 4 hidden sheets. A1 in every sheet has value 1 if to be included in the pdf, and 0 if not.

Being a newbie this is what I got so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("print1").Visible = True
Sheets("print2").Visible = True
Sheets("print3").Visible = True
Sheets("print4").Visible = True

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("print1", "print2")).Select  

iPtr = InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, ".")

If iPtr = 0 Then
sFileName = ActiveWorkbook.FullName & ".pdf"
Else
sFileName = Left(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, iPtr - 1) & ".pdf"
End If

sFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=sFileName, FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf")

If sFileName = "False" Then Exit Sub

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=sFileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, openAfterPublish:=True

Sheets("print1").Visible = False
Sheets("print2").Visible = False
Sheets("print3").Visible = False
Sheets("print4").Visible = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

1) It must be possible to make this more elegant; Sheets(Array("print1","print2" ...)).Visible = True will display the 4 sheets, but if set to false, it will only hide print1.

2) How can I obtain the values from A1 to construct a pdf with the right sheets?

3) I also want to have several copies of the total sheets in the same pdf. If I'm going to export print1 and print3 in the same pdf, I might want to have 2 copies; print1, print3, (and starting over:) print1, print3, in the same pdf file. The number of copies is obtained from lets say A2.

Comment: Perhaps you could construct an interim document only containing the sheets you want and then print the whole document as pdf

Answer (score 0):

See my code below which addresses parts 1 and 2 of your question. I removed the iPtr if statement lines, as any value they entered for the variable sFilename would be overwritten when sFilename is set equal to Application.GetSaveAsFileName.

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
sheet_name_array = Array("print1", "print2", "print3", "print4")
sfilename = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=sfilename, _
FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf")

If sfilename = "False" Then Exit Sub
For Each sheet_name In sheet_name_array
    Sheets(sheet_name).Visible = True
    If sheets(sheet_name).Range("A1") = 0 Then
        sheets(sheet_name).visible = false
    End If
Next

activeworkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=sfilename, _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, openAfterPublish:=True

For Each sheet_name In sheet_name_array
  Sheets(sheet_name).Visible = False
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```